# Snapper - how to undo changes, preserving timestamps?

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, btrfs, snapshot, file-metadata

I've damaged modification dates of files on my drive and I wanted to revert them using snapper snapshots but it doesn't seem to work, snapper only reverts content of files not modification dates. However in .snapshot directory files have proper, old timestamps. How do i completely restore disk state to certain snapshot so that all timestamps are the same as ones in stored snapshot?

Comment: I can rollback changes to certain snapshot and then it **does** preserve modification dates but also I can't make snapshots using snapper anymore as it throws errors so it doesn't seem to be convenient solution